# Spring Boot Validation : coming as {1} in error message

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-boot, bean-validation

Trying to archive below things in REST API using spring boot,

1. Entity classes annotated with

> @Size(min=4,message="Size.foo.name")
>
> private String name;

2. errorMessages.properties looks like below,

> errorMessages.properties
> Size.foo.name=Name field must be more than {1} characters

3. Added below custom class advice to map spring error message to pojo error style.

code

```
> @ControllerAdvice
@PropertySource("classpath:errorMessages.properties")
public class RestExceptionHandler 
{ 

@Autowired
private Environment environment;

@ExceptionHandler(MethodArgumentNotValidException.class)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)

public @ResponseBody ErrorDetail handleValidationError(MethodArgumentNotValidException manve, HttpServletRequest request) {
    List<FieldError> fieldErrors = manve.getBindingResult().getFieldErrors();
    for(FieldError fieldError : fieldErrors) {
        System.out.println(environment.getProperty(fieldError.getDefaultMessage())); //This prints Name field must be more than {1} characters
    }
    }

}
```

is there a way we can print the actual min size (4) as below and send to the user, or should i need to make some more configuration changes in classes?

> Name field must be more than 4 characters

Comment: What about `Name field must be more than {min} characters'?

Comment: I tried that, But the result was `Name field must be more than {min} characters'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773594/how-to-customize-hibernate-size-error-message-to-indicate-length-of-entered-fie

Comment: You miss something. I guess double quotes in the `@Size(min=4,message={Size.foo.name})`. Please post exact code you have

Comment: sorry edited my code... but no change still...

Comment: using Environment class to read the property file. Am i doing wrong should i need to used it over MessageSource class?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I understand what happens. You just retrieve the message property. The message is not evaluated.

You need a MessageSource here and pass FieldError to the message source to get message for.

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames" value="ValidationMessages"/>
</bean>
```

Then autowire the source in your controller

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
```

And to get your message, do as follows

```
for (Object object : bindingResult.getAllErrors()) {
    if(object instanceof FieldError) {
        FieldError fieldError = (FieldError) object;

        /**
          * Use null as second parameter if you do not use i18n (internationalization) or Locale to be specified if you need localized one
          */

        String message = messageSource.getMessage(fieldError, null);
    }
}
```

Got code examples from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751603/how-to-get-error-text-in-controller-from-bindingresult)

Comment: Added messagesource bean definition as mentioned above and applied this line also, messageSource.getMessage(fieldError, null);. But the result was "Name field must be more than {0} {1} characters" . Added {0} {1} also in the property file.. but min size value not getting appended in property message.

Comment: Try {min} and {max}

Comment: i added as below, Size.foo.name=Name must be more than {0} characters and Entity will be @Size(min=5,message="Size.foo.name"). this case it prints output as : Name must be more than {0} characters; If i specify   Size.foo.name=Name must be more than {min} & model as  @Size(min=5,message="{Size.foo.name}") then prints output as  (Exception):org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'Description must be more than 5 characters' for locale 'null'. Its searching for the code in properties....

Answer (score 0):

Change Min to max, min means minimum size is 4. And max means maximum size is about 20 or anything you want.

You type 
@Size(min=4,message="Size.foo.name")

private String name;

so you have to enter more than 4 character or equal.
if you take max than its a highest bound. like if max=20 than you can enter maximum 20 character.
and here min is lower bound so you have to enter minimum 4 character.

this is the solution