# Annotation for validating checkbox in Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, spring-annotations

I have some checkboxes in my Spring application. I am using the size annotation to check whether at least one checkbox has been clicked.

```
@Column(name = "workallot") 
@Size(min=1, max=6)
private Integer[] workAllotment;
```

It is generating the message for six checkboxes as below

> size must be between 1 and 6

But I want it to be like

> At least One Checkbox must be checked

How do i customize this message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Size(min=1, max=6 ,message = "At least One Checkbox must be checked")
```

Here is documentation which provides all parameters which annotation takes:

https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/Size.html

Also here is similar question :

[How to customize Hibernate @Size error message to indicate length of entered field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31773594/how-to-customize-hibernate-size-error-message-to-indicate-length-of-entered-fie)

Comment: thanks man, it is working. Btw, how do I use size annotation for a combo box which uses a foreign key column such as ManyToOne
JoinColumn(name = "dept_category") private DeptCategory deptCategory; to ensure one combobox item is selected

Comment: For this pursoses you can write your own implementation of hiberante validator 
Or you can create annoation which will be processed by ConstaintValidator<Annotationt,TypeToValidate>

Comment: Please show how should the validator implement ConstraintValidator<DeptCategoryConstraint, DeptCategory>

Comment: Could you provide mapping of entities in code in dialog or chat or here in comment that i will take a look at  ?) thanks

Comment: ManyToOne JoinColumn(name = "dept_branch")
private DeptBranch deptBranch;   It is part of Dept entity. The list of branches are shown in the combo box. @Mykhailo Moskura  code added.